# Couldn't find executable named camaracalibrator.py

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new to ros and its developing. By following [this](https://qiita.com/proton_lattice/items/aa805b28700575ba5ed3) link . i try calibrate uvc camera. Upto Installation of calibration related packages is done. But when i try to run

```
rosrun camera_calibration camaracalibrator.py --size 8x6 --square 0.025 image: = / image_raw
```

i get following errors . Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
rosrun camera_calibration camaracalibrator.py --size 8x6 --square 0.025 image: = / image_raw
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named camaracalibrator.py below /opt/ros/kinetic/share/camera_calibration
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/310596/couldn%27t-find-executable-named-camaracalibrator.py/) by [venushka](https://answers.ros.org/users/38991/venushka/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-12-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rasika](https://answers.ros.org/users/38891/rasika/) on 2018-12-13**:
I think you should try to get the dependencies and compiling the drivers as mentioned in this [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/camera_calibration/Tutorials/MonocularCalibration) first. and also try
$ rosmake camera_calibration
before running the camera calibration node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems the page you referring to has a typo. The node is actually called `cameracalibrator.py`. Also you added spaces in the ROS parameter assignment and the topic namespace, so pay attention.

The command should be:

```
rosrun camera_calibration cameracalibrator.py --size 8x6 --square 0.025 image:=/image_raw
```

The easiest way to avoid such problems is to type in everything yourself (do not copy/paste) and use bash-completion by pressing Tab. ROS command-line tools have pretty good completion support for most of parameters. In case of `rosrun` the completion is very helpful for package names (first parameter) and node names (second parameter); note, however, to make this to work for your own nodes the script should be actually marked as executable on the file system with, e.g. `chmod a+x <script name>`

---

Originally posted by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) with karma: 3060 on 2018-12-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [venushka](https://answers.ros.org/users/38991/venushka/) on 2018-12-14**:
@Boris thank you after running it i got this problem , do you have any idea
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53774299/unable-to-connect-uvc-camera-cameracalibrator-ros-kinetic
the usb camera that i use i tested with cheese command. it works well.

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2018-12-14**:
From a quick glance the command used on the link you've provided is also wrong: again there are spaces where they shouldn't be. Make sure that parameter assignment has no spaces, i.e. exactly like this `image:=/image_raw`. Also make sure that the topic exists with `rostopic info /image_raw`